# Don't understand how nextpow works

Tags: julia, pow

Recently I have been looking at how the `nextpow(a::Real, x::Real)` function works inside. The code is in `base/intfuncs.jl` of the Julia project. For the case `a == 2` there is an optimization as it is very common as case.

```
a == 2 && isa(x, Integer) && return _nextpow2(x)
```

However, I don't understand how this case works, I understand that this manipulation of bits must be something common to find the next `a^n`, but right now I don't understand it.

```
_nextpow2(x::Unsigned) = oneunit(x)<<((sizeof(x)<<3)-leading_zeros(x-oneunit(x)))
_nextpow2(x::Integer) = reinterpret(typeof(x),x < 0 ? -_nextpow2(unsigned(-x)) : _nextpow2(unsigned(x)))
```

In particular what I don't understand is the function `_nextpow2(x::Unsigned)`. Why does this help to get `a^n` larger than `x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for an unsigned Int, whatever its `bitstring()` is, say `0000000001xxxxxx`, the next power of 2 is just put a `1` at the last leading 0 and replace the entire `1xxxxxx` with `0000000`

```
julia> function f(x)
           @show bitstring(x)
           oneU = oneunit(x)
           Nbits = sizeof(x)<<3 # Nbits = Nbytes * 8
           Nzeros = leading_zeros(x - oneU)
           @show oneU
           @show Nbits
           @show Nzeros
           res = oneU <<(Nbits-Nzeros)
           @show bitstring(res)
           res
       end


julia> f(UInt16(18))
bitstring(x) = "0000000000010010"
oneU = 0x0001
Nbits = 16
Nzeros = 11
bitstring(res) = "0000000000100000"
0x0020
```